# completely disable vertical splits

Tags: split

I usually use vim inside screen over ssh and sometimes I notice problems  with the entire line "shifting over" when inserting text in a vertical split.

Any one of these programs could be responsible for messing up redisplay, but when it does happen, it's distracting.

Is there a way to completely disable vertical splits in vim (even via `C-w L` or things that open automatic splits or quickfix buffers) and make vim behave as if it weren't compiled with support for them.

Comment: Why not just don't use splits instead of trying to make it impossible to open a split?

Comment: because it seems like the kind of thing that might be hidden away in some config setting somewhere. And I do want to horizontal/`<c-w>s` splits still. It's also possible that someone has encountered the pathological shifting behavior and a found another way to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature which controls whether vim supports vertical splits is called `+vertsplit` and it is not possible to disable it alone at compile time. 
 Specifically, since patch 7.4.1611, vim always supports vertical splits when feature `+windows` is enabled (`FEAT_WINDOWS`).  The `FEAT_VERTSPLIT` preprocessor definition has been completely removed.

Incidentally, `:help feature-list` claims that `+vertsplit` is enabled only in the "normal" build and up, but this is wrong since `+windows` is enabled in the "small" build.

Comment: good find. posted a doc patch